# How to properly format wordpress post date in ionic angularjs

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework

I am working on a news blog mobile app using wordpress WP-API, everything else is working ok, but am having problem formatting the wordpress post date

this `{{post.date}}` gives me something like`2016-08-07T15:45:26`

How ever I want to format the date to have something like `dd-mm-year`, then in another one I get the time, instead of `15:45:26`, I want to get something like `3:45 pm`.

If possible, I will also like a filter that returns the date `2016-08-07T15:45:26` to something like `24 hours ago`, `2 days ago`, `1 week ago` etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem too. You may want to check this 
:https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jan/06/javascript-json-date-parsing-and-real-dates

Comment: Hi Dan - Thanks for the answer! It might be helpful to post a snippet capturing the important part of the solution -- this way if the link goes dead the answer will still be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a date manipulation library to convert the datetime provided by WordPress to the desired format. You may want to check out [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).